# MySQL rows are not being updated upon deletion

Tags: php, mysql

I am deleting a row (user) from the table Accounts and I am trying to set the values "Following Count" and "Follower Count" to their value with one subtracted. But for some reason that does not happen. The account deletes successfully, but the decrement doesn't happen.

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
        exit("Account doesn't exist");
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $id = $row["id"];
    $query = NULL;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Accounts` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    $arg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Following WHERE followingUserID = '$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($arg) >= 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($arg); $i++) {
            $arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($arg);
            $followingUserID = $arr['followingUserID'];
            $followedUserID = $arr['followedUserID'];
            $art = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `Following Count` FROM Accounts WHERE `id` = '$followedUserID'"));
            $followingCount = $art['Following Count'];
            $followingCount = $followingCount-1;
            $arts = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `Follower Count` FROM Accounts WHERE `id` = '$followingUserID'"));
            $followedCount = $arts['Followed Count'];
            $followedCount = $followedCount-1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET `Following Count` = '$followingCount' WHERE `id` = '$followingUserID'");
            mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET `Follower Count` = '$followedCount' WHERE `id` = '$followedUserID'");
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM Following WHERE followingUserID = '$id'");
        }
    }

    exit("Closed");
```

Comment: use mysql_query like this: mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error()); and you'll find your errors

Comment: please tell me you're sanitizing your inputs here -- also you have a race condition present in your code; you can use SQL to directly increment or decrement a numeric column by a set amount which would prevent this issue from occurring down the road

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was any apparent error which would stop me having to create a new user, follow another user and delete the user everytime until it works.

Comment: You havent checked any of the queries complete correctly, as a result there could be something else going wrong. Always check queries work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply do

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET `Following Count` = (`Following Count` - 1) WHERE `id` = '$followingUserID'");

 mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET `Follower Count` = (`Following Count` - 1) WHERE `id` = '$followedUserID'");
```

this way you wont need the 2 selects.